# Do matrices work within structs in C?

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I'm trying to make a struct that contains (in this example) the name of the item to buy in an array and in a matrix it's price and the weight of it I should buy. This is just an easy example of what i'm trying to do.
I use strcpy to declare the value just because I learned it this way, I don't if it's the best of the methods.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct Grocery_list{

    char item_name[2];
    double item_info[2][2]; 

}Grocery;


int main(){

Grocery market;
strcpy( market.item_name[0], "Apple");
strcpy( market.item_name[1], "Sugar");
strcpy( market.item_info[0][0],200); //apple weight
strcpy( market.item_info[1][0], 3); //apple price
strcpy( market.item_info[0][1], 300);
strcpy( market.item_info[1][1], 4);

printf("%f \n",martket.item_info[1][1]);

return 0;}
```

The errors are

```
teste.C: In function ‘int main()’:
teste.C:14:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 strcpy( market.item_name[0], "Apple");
                           ^
In file included from teste.C:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
teste.C:15:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 strcpy( market.item_name[1], "Sugar");
                           ^
In file included from teste.C:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
teste.C:16:35: error: cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 strcpy( market.item_info[0][0],200);
                                   ^
teste.C:17:34: error: cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 strcpy( market.item_info[1][0], 3);
                                  ^
teste.C:18:36: error: cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 strcpy( market.item_info[0][1], 300);
                                    ^
teste.C:19:34: error: cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
 strcpy( market.item_info[1][1], 4);
                                  ^
teste.C:21:16: error: ‘martket’ was not declared in this scope
 printf("%f \n",martket.item_info[1][1]);
                ^
```

Obviously, I searched for answers and solutions on Google, but everything I tried just caused other errors or even the same. For I'm new in programming in general I don't know what those errors mean.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with the struct. You're using strings and `strcpy` completely wrong.

Comment: `strcpy` is for copying **strings**.

Comment: `market.item_name[0]` is a character. `strcpy` requires a buffer to copy to, a buffer of the type `char*` or `char[]` (possibly imprecise)..

Comment: I suggest that you learn the difference between characters and strings.

Comment: "I use strcpy to declare the value" - What does that mean? As it stands, this makes no sense. And you apparrently should get a good (or better) C book and review the chapters about arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues:

Your struct doesn't have an array of strings.  It has an array of characters.  You need to add an extra dimension to `item_name` to have such an array:

```
typedef struct Grocery_list{

    char item_name[2][50];
    double item_info[2][2]; 

}Grocery;
```

Also, you're using `strcpy` to attempt to copy numerical values.  This function is used for copying strings.  Instead of using this function, perform a simple assignment:

```
market.item_info[0][0] = 200; //apple weight
market.item_info[1][0] = 3; //apple price
market.item_info[0][1] = 300;
market.item_info[1][1] = 4;
```

Lastly, you have a typo in your `printf` statement:

```
printf("%f \n",martket.item_info[1][1]);
```

It should be:

```
printf("%f \n",market.item_info[1][1]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now it was a silly mistake of mine! It did work now. Sorry for wasting your time on such a small thing.

Comment: @VictorRM Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The member `item_name` is an array of *two* characters, it's not an array of strings, it's just a single string (which can only hold a single character, remember that all strings have a special terminator character). You probably should make this an array of arrays of `char`, which means it's an array of strings:

```
char item_name[2][64];  // Two strings, each can hold 63 characters
```

The member `item_info` is an array of arrays of **`double`**. The `strcpy` function is for copying *strings* (arrays of `char`).

Remember that each element in an array is like a variable, which means you can just assign to it:

```
market.item_info[0][0] = 200; //apple weight
market.item_info[1][0] = 3; //apple price
market.item_info[0][1] = 300;
market.item_info[1][1] = 4;
```

And the last error is because you misspelled `market`.

All of this would be very obvious even to a beginner if you just *read* the error messages.

Comment: The array of strings I just figured out. The strcpy error was a silly mistake of mine. I've been working with strings/strcpy only for so long that I didn't see this petty mistake. Sorry for wasting your time on such a small thing. The misspell I copied here by mistake, I fixed it right after posting.

Just for the sake of saying: We don't know each other, but try being less rude, not everyone is used with programming or things of the sort. These errors of mine were purely caused by "being blind" to them and I recognize the triviality. But thank you again for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

1 - your declaration of the item_name[2] is correct but you used in the wrong way. this is actually logical error. you need enough room for saving your data such as: apple, sugar and ... the last character of string is '\0'. indeed you just declaring one character for saving "apple" or "sugar".

2 - `strcpy` is for manipulating of string or array of characters, so you are not authorized to use this function with numerical variables.

3 you have misspelling in last line (before returning to OS).